# how can I add more information in a method that inherit from another constructor class without replace that infomation by new one?

Tags: javascript, class, object, inheritance

I create a  construct class Person that has properties and methods. Then I created a other constructor Class Teacher that inherits from Person and has more properties by it own. What I wanted is to recover the information on the method greeting() of the Person () but also adding more information from the properties of  Teacher(). If I do nothing it normally inherits the greeting() method but I want to add more information so I thought to write again greeting() in the Teacher() class constructor. What happened was that the new method greeting() in Teacher class replaced the other method greeting() from Person class. 
What I want is to add , not replace one by other.

this is my code :

```
 class Person{
        constructor(first, last, age, gender, interests){
            this.name={
                first,
                last
            };

            this.age = age;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.interests = Array.isArray(interests) ? interests : [ interests ]

        }


        greeting(){
            let hobbie = this.interests.join(', ');
             return `Hi. I'm ${this.name.first} I am ${this.age} . I like ${hobbie}`;
        }

        farewell(){
            return `${this.name.first} has left the building. Bye for now!`;
        }
    }



    class Teacher extends Person{
        constructor(first, last,age, gender, interests, subject, grade){

            super(first, last,age,gender,interests);

            this._subject = subject;
            this.grade = grade;

        }

        *//here I wanted to add this information into the other that already exists .not replace on from another*
        greeting(){
                return `I am ${this._subject} teacher , I teach ${this.grade} grade `
        }


        get subject(){
            return this._subject;
        }

        set subject(newSubject){
            this._subject = newSubject;
        }
    }

    let snape = new Teacher('Severus', 'Snape', 45, 'male',['Potions','anoying students','using Sectumsempra on my enimies'], 'Dark arts', 5)
```

Comment: In Teacher you need to call `super.greeting()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Teacher` you can use `super` to invoke the parent class's methods.

```js
greeting(){
    return `${super.greeting()} I am ${this._subject} teacher , I teach ${this.grade} grade`;
}
```

Note that this will not work on static methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `super` to call a parent's method (just like how you called `Person`'s constructor through `Teacher`), like so:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(first, last, age, gender, interests) {
    this.name = {
      first,
      last
    };

    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.interests = Array.isArray(interests) ? interests : [interests]

  }


  greeting() {
    let hobbie = this.interests.join(', ');
    return `Hi. I'm ${this.name.first} I am ${this.age} . I like ${hobbie}`;
  }

  farewell() {
    return `${this.name.first} has left the building. Bye for now!`;
  }
}



class Teacher extends Person {
  constructor(first, last, age, gender, interests, subject, grade) {

    super(first, last, age, gender, interests);

    this._subject = subject;
    this.grade = grade;

  }
  
  // Call super.greeting() here
  greeting() {
    return `${super.greeting()} I am ${this._subject} teacher , I teach ${this.grade} grade `
  }


  get subject() {
    return this._subject;
  }

  set subject(newSubject) {
    this._subject = newSubject;
  }
}

let snape = new Teacher('Severus', 'Snape', 45, 'male', ['Potions', 'anoying students', 'using Sectumsempra on my enimies'], 'Dark arts', 5)
console.log(snape.greeting())
```